# Постраничная навигация на PHP

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Искал в инете нормальную статью о том, как собственноручно написать постраничную навигацию на PHP, но, увы, нормального материала по этой теме так и не нашёл. (( Можете подробно рассказать, как это можно реализовать?! Спасибо заранее!

Answer (score 3):

```
$page = (!empty($_GET['page']))?$_GET['page']:1;
if ($page < 1) $page = 1;
$per_page = 50;
```

Далее ищем запрос, которым возвращаются записи и делаем примерно следующе:

```
$count = 0;
$count_res = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(ID) as C FROM main_table WHERE [...];');
if ($count_db = mysql_fetch_object($count_res))
  $count = $count_db->C;
$total_pages = ceil($count / $per_page);
if ($page > $total_pages)
  $page = $total_pages;
```

Тут мы нашли текущую страницу с учетом кол-ва записей в БД, кол-во записей и кол-во страниц. Далее собственно правка запроса:

```
$records_res = mysql_query('[...] LIMIT '.(($page-1)*$per_page).', '.$per_page.';');
```

Получили записи текущей страницы.
Ссылки на страницы:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {
  if ($i != $page) {
    echo '<a class="page" href="?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
    } else echo $i;
  }
```

Comment: У Вас есть ошибочка, `"$records_res = mysql_query('[...] LIMIT '.($page-1).', '.$per_page.';');"` здесь `$page-1` нужно заменить на `($page-1)*$per_page`.

Comment: Допустим, пользователь специально прислал отрицательный номер страницы, почему бы ему не сказать, какой он криворукий, и из него хреновый хакер?

Comment: @gote спасибо, исправил.

@Андрюша ну как бы я не против) Но мне приятнее показывать это молча)

Answer (score 1):

Что вы имеете ввиду под "постраничная навигация" ?

Если например нужно сделать вывод 1000 фотографий из базы данных, скажем по 10 на страницу, то это делается с помощью самой БД конструкцией

- `LIMIT 0,10` - первая страница.
- `LIMIT 10,10` - вторая страница.
- `LIMIT 20,10` - третья страница.

.....

Если же нужно как то вывести те самые страницы (т.е навигация по этим страницам, то я рекомендую погуглить на тему "php pagger") или написать подобное самому. В этом нету ничего сложного.