# Постраничная навигация: проблема с while

Tags: php

Привет всем. Пишу сайт. Возникла проблема. Вывожу топик с постраничной навигацией, то есть имеется, например, 21 статья, на странице выдоится по 5 статей, получается 5 страниц будет, да? Вот только когда статьи заканчиваются в бд, то он просто циклом выводит форму -n количество раз, то есть 1 статью выведет и 4 просто, [вот картинка](http://imglink.ru/pictures/30-01-12/e91eed7d33b76e4ca4bec40f7fea31db.jpg). Вот код файла [article](http://vk.com/wall87524863_5829).

Answer (score 1):

Давайте изначально воспользуемся поиском на форуме ХешКода, который сразу выкинет один ответ.

[Постраничная навигация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/22506/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php)

И более будем пользоваться поиском на форуме, а не дублировать вопросы.
Считаю что данный вопрос можно закрыть или удалить.

Answer (score 1):

Один вопрос: на кой вам в цикле значение $num, если уже известно, что количество записей его не превысит? Да еще и цикл зачем-то при переборе значений стартуете... Поэтому:

```
echo "<table>"; 
while ( $postrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    echo "<tr> 
    <div class='face_m_hide'>
    <div class='face_pre'></div>
    <h2><span style='color: rgb(51, 51, 255);'><a href=''>Категория</a></span> - <a href='/post.php?id=".$postrow['id']."'>".$postrow['title']."</a></h2><br>
    <center><img style='' alt=''src='".$postrow['img']."'>
    <br>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://trollface.yaxakep.ru/share42.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>share42('http://trollface.yaxakep.ru/')</script>
    </center> 
    <br>
    </div> \r\n"; // <-- этот кусок кода - просто пипец. оставим его на совести автора
} 
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: самое страшное что вариант автора пишут в примерах на том же php.su  
Пример http://php.su/articles/?cat=examples&page=062

Comment: ГК плодится и размножается.  
Отдельное спасибо за строки

    while ( $postrow[] = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    echo "<table>";

Comment: Это просто пипец!

Answer (score 0):

В цикле while забыли **`"{}"`**, т.е. все echo у вас должны быть между фигурными скобками цикла while

Answer (score 0):

Да да я тоже с этим сталкивался решил проблему остановкой цикла :

```
for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
  if (empty($postrow[$i]['id'])) {break;}

}
```

так как $num задается в начале скрипта принудительно = 10 то и цикл for отработает 10 раз... 
Должно работать я именно этот скрипт и использовал в проекте.

Comment: да, товарищи, да... с грустью читаю что вы пишите.

>  <$num

зачем пробегать циклом от 0 до 10 и не использовать то кол-во записей которое вы вытаскиваете из БД?

Comment: Руслан благодарю вас! Вы очень помогли!)

Comment: этот ответ по-моему вообще не актуален, и неправилен.

По секрету скажу, вот отсюда и рождается "говнокод"

Comment: Знаю неправильно но это решает проблему. А как более рационально пусть решает автор вопроса либо так юзать либо делать с умом...

Comment: Это не решает проблему, это только запутывает.