# Реализация пагинатора

Tags: php

Нужно реализовать пагинатор, который выглядит так:

> `1 ... 17 18 19 [20] 21 22 23 ... 641`

И все это в одном классе... Help, please! Просто ранее с такими задачами не сталкивался...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ рядом [Постраничная навигация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/22506/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php)

```
/**
 * @param $total - Сколько всего страниц
 * @param $page - Текущая страница
 * @param $direct_url - URL адрес страниц этой ветки
 */
function Pegination($total, $page, $direct_url) {
    echo '<center><div class="pagination"><ul>';
    if ($page != 1) echo '<li><a href="' . URL . $direct_url . ($page-1) . '"><</a></li>';
    if ($page - 3 > 0) echo '<li><a href="' . URL . $direct_url .'1">1</a></li>';
    if ($page - 4 > 0) echo '<li><a href="#">...</a></li>';
    if($page - 2 > 0) echo '<li><a href="' . URL . $direct_url . ($page-2) . '">' . ($page-2) . '</a></li>';
    if($page - 1 > 0)echo '<li><a href="' . URL . $direct_url . ($page-1) . '">' . ($page-1) . '</a></li>';
    echo '<li class="active"><a href="' . URL . $direct_url . $page . '">' . $page . '</a></li>';
    if($page + 1 <= $total) echo '<li><a href="' . URL . $direct_url . ($page+1) . '">' . ($page+1) . '</a></li>';
    if($page + 2 <= $total) echo '<li><a href="' . URL . $direct_url . ($page+2) . '">' . ($page+2) . '</a></li>';
    if ($page + 4 <= $total) echo '<li><a href="#">...</a></li>';
    if ($page + 3 <= $total) echo '<li><a href="' . URL . $direct_url . $total . '">' . $total . '</a></li>';
    if ($page != $total) echo '<li><a href="' . URL . $direct_url . ($page+1) . '">></a></li>';
    echo '</ul></div></center>';
}
```

Comment: Круто, но надо ООП =(

Comment: А что мешает прикрутить? Здесь все, что надо есть. Формируется пегинация точно так, как вам нужно. Осталось только обернуть, как вам удобней)

Comment: Что-то не пойму, как запустить и как прикрутить...

Comment: Жесть! Просто жесть.

Answer (score -2):

```
class _Pagination{

static public function doit($total, $page, $direct_url){

... весть тот код.
}

}

вызов:
_Pagination::doit($total, $page, $direct_url);
```

только непонятно - а зачем тут ООП ?